# Callback function on pin state change

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing a simple python program to communicate with GPIO pins of the pi board.

As i wanted to make my program more portable, i created some pin(class pins) objects with the proper instances.

Also i created a father class (class board) which has a list made of class's pins objects among other stuff. So for every setup i call the proper board object.

So for every pin i want to handle i select the proper object to change its status if it has been set as an output. But if i have set the pin as an input i want to put a handler on the upper board class to inform me for these state change. Rpi.GPIO provides me the call_back option for the pin object but i want the call_back option to point on a method of board class.
Any suggestions will be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to check into the [Raspberry Pi SO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).  There's a lot of good info over there.

Comment: You could show the progress of your code and that you tried.

Comment: Could you expand on bit on exactly what problem you're having? Preferably including code, what exactly you're seeing, and what you expect.